# Why do I receive undefined value after reloading page in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars

So I have the following form:

```
template(name='editUser')
  .row
    .col-md-4.col-md-offset-4
      .page-header
        h1 Edit user
      form#edit-user-form
        .form-group
          label(for='name') Name
          input#user-name.form-control(type='text' placeholder='Name' value='{{user.name}}')
        .form-group
          label(for='email') E-Mail
          input#user-email.form-control(type='text' placeholder='E-Mail' value='{{getEmail user}}')
    button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Update
```

the following handlebars.js-Helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('getEmail', function (user) {
  if (user.emails && user.emails[0] && user.emails[0].address)
    return user.emails[0].address;
  return '';
  });
```

and the following iron-Router code:

```
    EditUserController = RouteController.extend({
      template: 'editUser',
      waitOn: function () {
        return Meteor.subscribe('user', this.params._id);
      },
      data: function () {
        return {
          user: Meteor.users.findOne( { _id: this.params._id } )
        };
      }
});
```

If I run my application and click on the link to the edit-User-Form I can see the E-Mail Address. But if I change my code and Meteor automatically refreshes the page, the E-Mail-Field is empty and the console says, that it can't fetch the value of undefined.

If I use the same form, but with a with-Helper, the E-Mail is displayed even if Meteor automatically refreshes the page:

```
template(name='editUser')
  .row
    .col-md-4.col-md-offset-4
      .page-header
        h1 Edit user
      form#edit-user-form
        with user
          .form-group
            label(for='name') Name
            input#user-name.form-control(type='text' placeholder='Name' value='{{name}}')
          .form-group
            label(for='email') E-Mail
            input#user-email.form-control(type='text' placeholder='E-Mail' value='{{getEmail this}}')
      button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Update
```

Why is this so? And should I always use the with-Helper if I get single Results (only one Result to display)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `Meteor.users.findOne` with `Meteor.users.find`.

When `findOne` doesn’t find anything, it returns `undefined` which causes your error; when `find` doesn’t find anything, it returns an empty cursor which Meteor knows what to do with. Essentially all you were doing by adding `with` was to cause Meteor to check if the value was undefined, but that check isn’t necessary for a cursor, empty or otherwise.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! So it's recommended to use find() instead of findOne. Can you say when should I use find() and when should I use findOne()? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use `findOne` anywhere, often it’s more convenient than `find`; just know that when you use it, you need to check for the possibility of it returning `undefined` when it doesn’t find anything. In this particular circumstance, `each` complains when you send it `undefined`, but not when you send it an empty cursor, so it’s just easier to use `find`. You could alternatively use `findOne` but then check for it being `undefined` before returning the results to `each`, and changing the results value from `undefined` to `[]` (an empty array) to avoid the error.

Comment: Also note that when using `find`, if you really just want one result, you should add `limit: 1` to the query unless you know it will never return more than one (you’re searching for an `_id`, for example).